LMM: effect of day may differ between subjects - fixed or random effect?
We tested 12 animals in a test with three phases (a/b/c) in three conditions (C1/C2/C3) on nine days, i.e. every animal experienced each condition three times. On each day, four animals were tested in each of the three conditions. Here is a reduced example table with three animals on two days:

I plan to analyse count data collected during the phases (one data point per phase) with a generalised linear mixed model. The effect of interest is the condition * phase interaction - we would expect similar values in the first phase (habituation, same treatment regardless of condition), but different values according to condition in the other phases. The model would need to have a random intercept for each animal, and as the reactions of the animals towards the different conditions and phases will differ between individuals, we would also need random slopes for them.
With condition and phase dummy-coded, the basic model would thus be
changes ~ phase * cond + 
          (1 + cond.code.2 + cond.code.3 + phase.code.2 + phase.code.3 | animal)

The day needs to be entered as a random effect, as we could have sampled on different days. This should be on an individual basis ("animal days"), because the reactions of the animals to the specific circumstances of each day (e.g. irritability caused by differing insect pressure) are expected to differ between individuals:
changes ~ phase * cond + 
          (1 + cond.code.2 + cond.code.3 + phase.code.2 + phase.code.3 | animal) + 
          (1 | day.in.animal)

The question is: Do I also need to enter the day as a fixed effect? Maybe for a general effect of day, in contrast to the "animal days"? If so, it would need to be in a three-way interaction with phase and condition, and there would need to be also a random slope for it, because the effect of condition on the effect of the phase will probably differ between days, and how they differ will be different for each individual. I am not interested in the effect of the day itself, but if it influences my effect of interest, will a random effect as in the model above be sufficient?

You can't enter day as both random effect grouping variable and as a (categorical) fixed effect as these "use" the same variance in outcome. Also, you have rather little data for a very complex model, I doubt it will converge I'm sorry to say.

I agree with @Sointu about having a variable be both fixed and random. It makes no sense. It sounds like day should be random, and that you have crossed random effects. So no 3-way interaction, just the model specified as you have it. It is a somewhat complex model, so you may have convergence issues, in which case, you may want to drop one or more of the random slopes

Thank you to both of you! I think I'll stick with the second model, then.
